# Get Unique Count Using MYSQLI Query

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, count, distinct

I have one table called quiz_data which have column called id, user_id and user_band which have value like below

```
id user_id user_band
1      1      A
2      2      B
3      1      A
4      3      A
```

I want get total unique user_band with keep in mind user_id will count only one time. from above example I want result called userband A = 2 and B = 1. 
I have tried like below

```
select('user_band,COUNT(distinct(user_id)) as count')from quiz_data GROUP BY user_band ORDER BY user_band
```

but its not working properly. Let me know if someone can help me for same. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax you want is:

```
select user_band, count(distinct user_id) no_users
from quiz_data
group by user_band
order by user_band
```